# Three.js WaterDemo port form r48 to r60

Tags: google-chrome, migration, three.js, version

I'm trying to port this demo (http://www.chromeexperiments.com/detail/waterstretch)
from three.js r48 to r60.
But on even r49 I'm struggling to get it work. The demo just shows a blank screen and no 
errors console.
In the changelog from r48 to r49 I couldn't find anything helpful.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version updated to three.js r60: https://github.com/zebradog/water